# MediaType of REST

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I am beginner in REST web services.

I wrote a program of REST to display the HTML or XML. The @Path annotation's value is `@Path("{typeDocument}")`. There are two methods for GET :

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
public String getXml(@PathParam("typeDocument") String typeDocument)
```

to display XML file,
and

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String getHtml(@PathParam("typeDocument") String typeDocument)
```

to display HTML.

The browser Firefox always excutes getHtml() when URL is either

http://localhost:8080/sources/html or http://localhost:8080/sources/xml

But IE always excutes `getXml()`.

How to excute the correct method, as defined by URL, in different browser ?

Comment: A little bit of care over formatting goes a long way....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using MediaType.APPLICATION_XML instead of TEXT_XML.

That being said, this isn't the best use of JAX-RS - especially if you're using RestEASY or any other implementation with JAXB support.

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Path("/{typeDocument}")
public MyObject getXml(@PathParam("typeDocument") String typeDocument) {
 myObjectService.get(typeDocument);
}


@XmlRootElement(name="myObject")
public class MyObject {
// Some properties
}
```

would be a much easier method to maintain. You can also use JSPs for the HTML.

See http://java.dzone.com/articles/resteasy-spring for a good example (using Spring).

Comment: Thank you very much. I resoved this problem.
I removed @Path from class, and added @Path before each method, as this :

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Path("xml")
public String getXml()

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
@Path("html")
public String getHtml()

Now it runs well.

Comment: Glad to be of assistance. If the problem is solved you should accept an answer so others know you no longer require help.